# Fail to add plot(created by PLOTLY package) in pptx with ReporteRs

Tags: r, plotly, reporters

I am trying to use ReporteRs to create a powerpoint by R. But when I use `addplot` to insert plotly objects into pptx, it gives me an empty slide. I have done as the reference manual says for ggplot2 objects: `fun = print` and an extra `x` specifies a plot object, but it doesnt work. Perhaps a plotly object is not supported by the ReporteRs package ?

Here is my code:

```html
library(webshot)
library(ReporteRs)
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)
library(MASS)
  
 
myplot=plot_ly(iris,x=~Species,y=~Sepal.Width,type='bar') %>%
  layout(
    title = "Sepal width of each type",
    yaxis2 = list(
      tickfont = list(color = "red"),
      overlaying = "y",
      side = "right",
      title = ""),
    xaxis = list(title=""))

myggplot<-ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_bar(stat="identity")

pptx(title="title") %>%
  addSlide(slide.layout = "Title and Content") %>%
  addPlot(fun=print,x=myplot,vector.graphic=F) %>%
  writeDoc(file = "SepalData.pptx" )
```

`x=myplot` and `x=myggplot` give different outcomes.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?

Comment: Sure. I also tried `fun=function()plot_ly(iris,x=~Species,y=~Sepal.Width,type='bar') %>%
  layout(
    title = "Sepal width of each type",
    yaxis2 = list(
      tickfont = list(color = "red"),
      overlaying = "y",
      side = "right",
      title = ""),
    xaxis = list(title=""))`, still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plotly objects are htmlwidgets, this format is not supported by ReporteRs.